# Difference between Systick exception handler and Sytick interrupt handler. do all cpu exceptions also have IRQ handlers?

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx, cortex-m, cortex-m4

**THIS IS WHAT MY UNDERSTANDING**
Is Systick an exception or an interrupt? since it is one among the list of cpu exceptions, I'm coming to conclusion, **systick** as an exception.
since it is an exception, it is having an exception handler, SysTick_Handler(), to take care of whenever an exception arises.

**THIS ARE MY DOUBTS**

1. If SYSTICK an exception, then why there is also an interrupt handler like **hal_systick_IRQHandler()**?
2. Do all cpu exceptions, also have their corresponding IRQ handlers?
3. to my understanding, exceptions and interrupts are handled by NVIC, by running their respective handlers.
   So, when Systick exception occurs, which function NVIC will execute. Systick_Handler or Hal_systic_IRQhandler ?
   4.purpose and use cases of each of those handler functions.
4. can't we write this below code

```
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  HAL_IncTick();
  HAL_SYSTICK_IRQHandler();
}
```

like this

```
void HAL_SYSTICK_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_IncTick();
}
```

As i'm new to Embedded programming, so either my understanding or my doubts could be wrong. pls explain. An elaborate explanation would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

The functions are referenced in the interrupt vector table, which is (typically) part of the (assembly language) startup code.

Different vendors use different startup code that usually does the same thing, but that can cause the function names to be different. Since the reference is by *name*, spelling has to be correct.

You can look up the funtion names in the startup code file itself - it is somewhat readable even if you don't know much about assembly language.

Note that the mechanism for calling exeption handlers and interrupt handlers is exactly the same, the name is looked up from the interrupt vector table during linking. At run time the MCU will use the function *address* from that vector table - the interrupt/exception number determines which address it uses.

Comment: @Tubo J. Thanks for the reply but couldn't understand how the answer is relevant to the question. Do you mean to say that there is possibility that an exception or an interrupt could have multiple Handlers.

Comment: Each exception/interrupt has one vector. If you so desire you can chain multiple handlers but that rarely makes much sense. It looks like you might be using CubeMX or whatever the STM32 library is called, so read the doc on that. It might just be adding a layer of abstraction.

Comment: @Kartman. you mean, that there is a possibility that, exception calls its corresponding exception handler.. and that exception handler calls the IRQHandler, of that exception.

Comment: Note that the terms interrupt and exception can be used interchangeably, but more precisely an exception is an arm core interrupt vs an interrupt from a peripheral. So don’t get hung up on the terminology. Nevertheless, you need to refer to the code/documentation of the framework you’re using. Without the likes of cubemx, there is no HAL functions, so this is most likely where your confusion is creeping in. If you want a precise answer, then you’ll have to tell us what cpu and tools you are using or simply put your detective hat on and follow the code. It starts at the vector table.